# Get Exported Values from ServiceLocator by type

Tags: wpf, types, prism, mef, service-locator

I am trying to get Values from the ServiceLocator (MEF) by Type.

Example: Give all Controls that are type DMControl

```
IEnumerable<DMControl> list = ServiceLocator.Current.GetAllInstances<DMControl>();
```

list is empty. When i open up the list from ServiceLocator, there are Controls like that.
If i getting an instance of DMControl with the export key, works too. Why can't i get all controls of one type?!

Comment: I can't really understand exactly what's your problem? So are you saying you do receive results? or that you always get an empty collection? I didn't quite get that. @jberger - ServiceLocator is a common class that comes with MEF, maybe its code is on codeplex, but it's not his own class if that's what you meant.

Comment: any place in code that's adding `DMControl` types to the `ServiceLocator`..

Comment: The problem was, that the controls got a key.